# MySQL Workbench edit data

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

MySQL Workbench allows one edit Select query results which seems a nice feature, yet if I rerun query the changes do not stick. Is there way to edit tables (preferably in query results). I can run update query, yet sometimes editing is more convenient.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to click "Apply" after you finish editing the data, otherwise it will not save the changes.